# What exactly is the difference between {$taxonomy}_add_form_fields and {$taxonomy}_add_form

Tags: wordpress

I'm observing very similar behavior for both `{$taxonomy}_add_form_fields` and `{$taxonomy}_add_form` is there a diference and what it is? I understand the semantic difference of form and form field, but I'm wondering how WP sees it.

There is no record of it in the Wordpress Codex and Developer part of the Wordpress website is giving almost same description.

See for yourself:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/taxonomy_add_form_fields/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/taxonomy_add_form/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking a look into `/wp-admin/edit-tags.php`, we can see the `do_action( "{$taxonomy}_add_form", $taxonomy );` is used to replace to preceding deprecated filters. That's why it was added.

Getting to the "difference" between them, you could see in the code that the filter `{$taxonomy}_add_form_fields` is used to add data to the form just before the submit button has been created, while the other filter `{$taxonomy}_add_form` is used after the submit button (but still before the closing tag `</form>`.

Usually, you could think about putting visible fields before the submit button and then adding hidden fields right after it. But it's not a sort of great difference between them.

Answer (score 1):

Both of actions is in the form tag.

But, `{$taxonomy}_add_form_fields` action is before submit button and `"{$taxonomy}_add_form"` action is after submit button and `add_tag_form` action.